# Metaprogramming: adding equals(Object o) and hashCode() to a library class

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, equals, hashcode

I have a library of domain objects which need to be used in the project, however we've found a couple of the classes haven't got an `equals` or `hashCode` method implemented.

I'm looking for the simplest (and Grooviest) way to add those methods. Obviously I could create a subclass which only adds the methods, but this would be confusing for developers used to the library and would mean we'd have to refactor existing code.

It is not possible to get the source changed (currently).

If I could edit the class I would just use the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation to carry out an AST transformation (at compile time?), but I can't find a way to instruct the compiler to carry out the transformation on a class which I can't directly annotate.

I'm currently trying to work up an example using the `ExpandoMetaClass`, so I'd do something like:

```
MySuperClass.metaClass.hashCode = { ->
  // Add dynamic hashCode calculation bits here 
}
MySuperClass.metaClass.equals = { ->
  // Add dynamic hashCode calculation bits here 
}
```

I don't really want to hand-code the `hashCode`/`equals` methods for each class, so I'm looking for something dyamic (like `@EqualsAndHashCode`) which will work with this.

Am I on the right track? Is there a groovier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AST Transforms are only applied at compile time, so you'll get no help from the likes of `@EqualsAndHashCode`. MetaClass hacks are going to be your only option. That said, there are more-elegant ways to impose MetaClass behavior.

**Shameless Self Plug** I did a talk about this kind of stuff last year at SpringOne 2GX: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/groovy-app-architecture

In short, you might find benefit in creating extensions (unless you're in Grails) - http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/01/groovy-goodness-adding-extra-methods.html, or by explicitly adding mixins - http://groovy.codehaus.org/Runtime+mixins ... But in general, these are just cleaner ways to do the exact same thing you're already doing.

Comment: That's great, thanks Dan. The runtime mixins approach is definitely a little cleaner and less confusing to the uninitiated.